# Django - Questionnaire - ModelFormSet - Cannot assign

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset

Alright, so I'm following a tutorial on creating a small questionnaire with Django.

A User can create a survey with different multiple choice questions. Since they're multiple choice questions, users can also set the options for the questions.

A "survey taker" can then start a survey, select his or her preferred questions and submit the form.

I would like to only show a single question per page so I'm trying to work with modelformset_factory and implement pagination using the build in paginator.

The form is rendered correctly and a user can submit an answer, however, the form fails before "formset.is_valid()", I just can't figure out why;

> ValueError at /surveys/1/submit/4/
>
> Cannot assign "'2'": "Answer.option" must be a "Option" instance.

So I can not save an integer and I somehow have to relate the integer with the id from the option model... But I can't access cleaned_data yet so I guess I'm missing something here. Did I forget something within the formset?

I've been staring at this for a while now so any help is appreciated.

#Views

```
def submit(request, survey_pk, sub_pk):
    # Let's retrieve the survey which is created by the survey-taker
    try:
        survey = Survey.objects.prefetch_related("question_set__option_set").get(
            pk=survey_pk, is_active=True
        )
    except Survey.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404() 

    try:
        submission = survey.submission_set.get(pk=sub_pk, is_complete=False)
    except Submission.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404() 

    # Retrieve all question associated with this survey 
    questions = survey.question_set.all() 
    # Get all related options from the questions
    options = [q.option_set.all() for q in questions]

    form_kwargs = {"empty_permitted": False, "options": options,}
    # Setup a formset utilizing a ModelFormSet
    AnswerFormset = modelformset_factory(
        Answer, 
        form=AnswerModelForm, 
        formset=BaseAnswerFormSet,
        exclude=(), 
        extra=len(questions), 
    )

    if request.method == "POST":
        print("Request.POST", request.POST)
        # This is where the problem starts
        formset = AnswerFormset(request.POST, form_kwargs=form_kwargs)
        print("Formset: ", formset)
        if formset.is_valid():
            print("Formset is valid")
            with transaction.atomic():
                for form in formset:
                    Answer.objects.create(
                        option_id=form.cleaned_data["option"],
                        submission_id=sub_pk,
                    )

                    submission.is_complete = True 
                    submission.save 
                return redirect("survey-thanks", pk=survey_pk)
    else:
        
        formset = AnswerFormset(form_kwargs=form_kwargs)
        print(form_kwargs)

    question_forms = zip(questions, formset)
    return render(
        request,
        "survey/submit.html",
        {
            "survey": survey,
            "question_forms": question_forms,
            "formset": formset
        }
    )
```

#forms

```
# Setup a Modelformset
class AnswerModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Answer 
        fields = "option",
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        options = kwargs.pop("options")
        # Options must be a list of Option objects
        choices = {(o.pk, o.text) for o in options}
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        option_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices, widget=forms.RadioSelect, required=True)
        self.fields["option"] = option_field 


class BaseAnswerFormSet(forms.BaseFormSet):
    def get_form_kwargs(self, index):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs(index)
        kwargs["options"] = kwargs["options"][index]
        return kwargs
```

#models

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    """An answer a survey's questions."""

    submission = models.ForeignKey(Submission, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    option = models.ForeignKey(Option, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
option_id=form.cleaned_data["option"],
```

is the suspect, it may require an option instance, even though you are trying to pass the id. Try changing **option_id** to **option__id** and explicitly setting the form.cleaned_data["option"] to int. Another way to to is to pull the option manually and pass it directly:

`option = Option.object.get(id=int(form.cleaned_data["option"]))`

Comment: That's what I thought but cleaned_data isn't available yet, the code is stuck before formset.is_valid() get's called.

Comment: the you shoud look into (BaseAnswerFormSet.get_form_kwargs) kwargs["options"] = kwargs["options"][index], and the (AnswerModelForm.__init__)self.fields["option"] = option_field add some trace there and try to localize the crash site more accurately